# Elm Language, mouse tracer

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I am trying to make a simple mouse follower. A blue circle who's position updates with my mouse position. What is wrong with my update and view that won't allow this?

```
type alias Model = { position : { x : Int, y : Int} }

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model,Cmd.Cmd Msg)
update (MouseMsg pos) model = ({ position = {x = model.position.x + pos.x, y = model.position.y + pos.y} },Cmd.none)


view : Model -> Html.Html Msg
view model = let
posX = toString model.position.x
posY = toString model.position.y
in
  svg [width "600",height "600"] [circle [cx "300",cy "300", r "50", fill "blue", x posX, y posY] []]
```

Answer (score 3):

The `<circle>` SVG element does not support `x` or `y` attributes (they're silently ignored). `cx` and `cy` are the coordinates of the center, so you need to pass `posX` and `posY` to them:

Change:

```
circle [cx "300",cy "300", r "50", fill "blue", x posX, y posY]
```

To:

```
circle [cx posX, cy posY, r "50", fill "blue"]
```